# How do I create an array loop where only the most recent n particles are drawn?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, loops

This diagram is the clearest way I can think to describe this:

```
0---------   
00--------   
-000------ 
--000-----
---000----
----000---
-----000--
------000-
-------000 // at this point the earlier particles get repopulated in the array
0-------00
00-------0
000------- // at this point the last positions in the array can get seeded
-000------ // and so on to infinity.
```

The 0's represent the i values in an array of 10 objects counted through for the while loop. In my situation they represent active particles. I want to re-use the array, re-seeding objects at the beginning while 300 particles are being cycled through continually.

This is a really hard question to describe so bear with me.

Currently I generate an array of particle objects, and then I loop through all the objects with a maximum of 300 active particles at a time. These 300 active particles move through the array when one particle is created the old one dies. I do this by simply updating the start and end values according to the situation. (i = x; i < y)

For example (each 0 represents a particle object, only 3 particles exist at a time for performance reasons).

Up until frame 10 is what my current array loop does. Particles older than 300 from the last particle created are not drawn or checked for collisions etc. The problem is I can't figure out how to have particles from the beginning of the array drawn at the same time as the remaining particles at the end of the array without duplicating all my loops and variables and adding more conditionals and bloat. I could of course wait for all the particles to die out before starting again, but I can't interrupt the particle flow.

Comment: This is very confusing. An array of 10 objects ? 300 particles ? 3 particles for performance reasons ? What's an "old" particle ? Is it 300 particles that you send one after the other whenever there are less than 3 particles already in your array ? A minimal code example will probably help.

Comment: Oh, my example diagram is only 10 particles, because I can't write out all the particles in my actual array visually. The 3 particles represent the 300 particles in my actual array. My total array size is 1000, but functionally the question is the same whether it's dealing with a 10 object array of a 10,000 object array. There's no reason to have the array size that large except I seed the objects with values from sin functions with very long wavelengths etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, you want a way to naturally wrap around an array using index.

You are looking for the modulo operator.

```
Particle[] arr;
int x;
int y;
while (true) {
    // case x <= y: distance between x and y is y - x
    // case x > y: distance between x and y is y + arr.length - x
    for (int i = x > y ? x : x + arr.length; i < y + arr.length; i++) {
        int index = i % arr.length;
        // Update particles
    }
    x = (x + 1) % arr.length;
    y = (y + 1) % arr.length;
}
```

Modulo operator is useful in emulating "wrapping around" when an index grows over the size of an array.

It might be more intuitive to keep track of number of active particles `d` and calculate `y` using `y = x + d`. Here is an implementation of what you describe in the diagram:

```
Particle[] arr;
int targetD = 300; // Target (maximum) number of active particles
int x = 0;
int y;
int d = 0; // Number of active particles, d stands for distance between x and y
while (true) {
    y = x + d;
    for (int i = x; i < y; i++) {
        int index = i % arr.length;
        // Update particles using arr[index]
    }
    if (d < targetD) {
        d++;
    } else {
        x = (x + 1) % arr.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Assuming I understand your question correctly* - Can you illustrate what you implemented? Like explaining the code a bit, what happens?

Comment: Awesome. It seems modulo was what I was looking for. I'll mock up a simple example and see if I can get it to work for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I was able to get it to work on a simple mockup, the way I worked out collisions and some other problems is a little non-standard so now trying to see if I can get it to work with my program but this looks perfect. You understood what I was trying to ask 100%. I'm new to java and this is a pretty powerful new concept in my bag. Thanks.

Comment: Just wanted to update that I was able to use the concept and make it work perfectly. The way you wrote out your example made it crystal clear how it was working. Wish I could give you more thumbs up.